# Strategies to let a separate app talk to javascript in the browser

Tags: browser, html, cookies

Here's the scenario: we have a separate app running on a computer (outside of the browser). It creates a folder with 10,000 downloaded thumbnail images.

In the browser, we have a traditional browser app. It lets you browse through these images. In order to speed up the browsing dramatically, I want to let the app get the images from the local drive, if available, ie. `img src="C:/..."` instead of `img src="http://..."`

The app can talk to the server, and let it know the path to the images.

I'm trying to figure out how to (lightweight) let the browser know that on this particular computer, we have a folder with images, whereas on another particular computer, we may not.

My best guess so far is have the app write a cookie to the browser. Is that the easiest/most elegant/most lightweight way of doing this?

Comment: What is the amount of information necessary to pass from the out of browser app to the browser app? Are you passing a boolean, a single folder name, or a list of full file path values?

Comment: Just a single value, it just needs to say: now that the server knows that computer X has images cached on it, the computer that you are now on is computer X.

Answer (score 0):

The app could just add some javascript variable to the page.  e.g. for PHP

```
if($hasImagesFolder) echo "var hasImagesFolder = true;";
else echo "var hasImagesFolder = false;";
```